# JMeter : log impact on results

Tags: logging, jmeter

I'm actually trying to test a web app on a JBoss 7.1.1 server with JMeter.

This is the process :

```
JMETER   --SOAP-->   WebService1   --SOAP-->   WebService2
                                                    |
JMETER <--response--  WebService1     <--response--
```

The fact is, for each process, I have a lots of logs which appear in my "Command Prompt" and they are also saved in a log file. (for 1 SOAP request send, I get at least 50 lines of log)

This are basic tests, I'm running my server and JMeter on the same machine.

My question is : Does this logs have any effect on the results ? I mean an important effect.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging is IO process which consumes RAM, CPU and especially affects disk operations. Printing 50 lines per SOAP request is definitely not expected behavior. Fortunately JMeter logging is controllable via properties.

Following set used to work fine:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

Put lines above to `user.properties` file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation.

Refer to [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) post for another piece of advice on JMeter optimization.

Comment: Thanks ! That helped me more that what I was looking for at first !